# IIS Reporting wrong Time and TimeZone

Tags: wcf, datetime, iis, timezone

Everything i am reading says that IIS uses the local machine time and timezone, and as such to change the effective time zone and/or time, all i need do is change the time and timezone for the server, and it will change the effective time and timezone that the IIS server sees, and i have a server running a simple WCF service that this just does not seem to be working for me.

This server is is located on Pacific turf in a leased farm, but has had an Eastern timezone configured on it since we first set it up. I have tried resetting everything and even tried bouncing the box, so i am sure it is not cached Time values or something so simple. However upon break-pointing my WCF code to try and understand why it is passing out dates that are off by three hours to all consuming services, i found that IIS is convinced it is in Pacific Timezone, despite everything being configured otherwise.

System.TimeZoneInfo.Local reports that it is in Pacific Time, and DateTime.Now give me a timestamp that is off by three hours, and i can not seem to figure out how to convince IIS that it needs to use Eastern Time as the effective time zone for the records it is creating and handing out.

Answer (score 3):

In general, server-side code should *not* depend on the local time zone.  Calling either `TimeZoneInfo.Local` or `DateTime.Now` from a server application is usually a mistake.  See [The Case Against DateTime.Now](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/).

The best practice would be to leave your server set to Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), and write your application to manage time zones internally.  If you are dependent on Eastern time, then your *code* should do something like:

```
TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
DateTime now = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, tz);
```

That said, if `TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id` is returning `Pacific Standard Time`, then there are only two possible explanations:

- Your system is indeed set for the Pacific time zone.
- Your system *was* set for the Pacific time zone, but you changed it without restarting or calling [`TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.clearcacheddata.aspx).

Since you've eliminated both of these explanations in how you described the problem, I can only say that there must be something wrong with how you are setting the time zone.

Try using `tzutil.exe` on an Administrator elevated command prompt.  `tzutil /g` will give you the current time zone setting.  `tzutil /s "Eastern Standard Time"` will set your time zone for US Eastern Time.  Be sure to restart your application after changing the time zone, either by recycling the application pool in the management console, using `iisreset`, restarting IIS, or (if you must) rebooting the server.

You can also just make the change through the time zone control panel.

If you are saying you've done all of that, and you're getting `"Eastern Standard Time"` back from `tzutil /g`, but `TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id` is returning `"Pacific Standard Time"` even though you've rebooted, then I call BS.  That's just not possible.  Perhaps there's a simpler explanation, such as maybe you're deploying to multiple servers and you're setting the time zone on a different server than you're getting the results from.

Comment: Afraid my problem is just a little deeper than using DateTime.Now, i was using those two calls from the immediate window in Visual Studio to confirm the problem. I inherited an old WSE service that communicates in DataSet object to provide data connectivity for an ASPX application on another server. I converted it to WCF, but was unable address the bad procedure of talking in Datasets for the sheer amount of code involved.

Comment: All of our DB DateTimes are already recorded in UTC, and the ASPX service handles converting to client time, but WCF is assuming the date to be in local time, and adjusting them by three hours on the receiving end because it is perceiving a timezone differential. Based on the sheer amount of code involved,

Comment: I'm not prepared to address every recordset to convert all dates to local time so the receiving service can convert them back to UTC just so ASPX can properly convert to client time. WCF assuming local time is not an issue because both APSX and WCF are supposed to be in the same timezone, but with WCF assuming the wrong timezone our UTC dates are getting mangled in transition.

Also, TZUtil is also reporting "Eastern Standard Time", i will bounce the entire server, not just the IIS Web Server tonight and see what the result is, and report back tomorrow.

Comment: Until then, i have an image showing my condition this morning available at http://managepro.com/TimeZoneError.jpg

Comment: Is remote desktop or terminal services being used here?  Also - in the image, besides the time zones being different, there is a 17 minute difference between the two timestamps.  Was it idle for that long before you took the screenshot?

Comment: Yas as i indicated, the data server with the WCF service is housed in a server farm with one service provider, the ASPX front end is housed on a different server with a different service provider, RDP is used for desktop access to both boxes. And yes, i took approximately 20 minutes researching before entering a question of my own. Everything i was reading indicated that there was no way of maintaining separate time zones for IIS, and IIS was supposed to rely on Server Time and Time Zone for any date information.

Comment: You may also notice that i specifically called a ClearCachedData() to assure that cache was cleared before requesting timezone and date, what is not shown is that i restarted the WCF site, recycled the application pool, and before reaching out for help, even tried stopping and restarting the entire web server. In approximately 2 hours, enough of our clients will be offline that i can afford to bounce the entire server, so i should have some more news after that step is completed.

Comment: Ok, box was bounced around 7:30 this AM, before start of business, problem still persists. I have a new image ( http://managepro.com/ProblemPersists.jpg ) showing Visual studio still misreporting the time zone, i included a utility from NirSoft showing the reboot date and this time there is no time lag between the DateTime.Now call and the screen shot, but as you can see, IIS is still misreporting the time zone for our WCF Service, while the desktop timezone is still tuned to a different time zone. You called 'BS' and i wish that were the case, but our timezone problem remains...

Comment: I'm confused about one thing.  Is VS on your production server?

Comment: Also, is it possible that your remote server is enabled for full the Terminal Services role and has [Time Zone Redirection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725887.aspx) enabled?    That's probably a long shot, but could explain some things.  Still, I would expect the remote clock to match `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: And this may sound like a silly question, but are you sure you're checking `DateTime.Now` and `TimeZoneInfo.Local` from the remote computer and not your own? And are you sure you're changing the time zone of the remote computer and not your own?  Sometimes with remote desktop, it's easy to mix up which task bar or window you're looking at.   I know I've done that once or twice!  Could it be that simple?   (Just thinking hard for alternate explanations).

Comment: Also, if you're trying to remote debug from VS on a dev box to a remote IIS server, I'm not sure whether the immediate window would evaluate the time zone on the remote server or on the local machine.  You could try making a simple console application to write the local time zone id and time instead of using the VS immediate window and just run that on the remote machine directly.

Comment: You should also double check the source code.  Are you sure it's using the local time zone? Perhaps it's hard-coded for Pacific Standard Time or pulling the time zone from a database or some other source.

Comment: Ok, one at a time, yes, we have Visual Studio 2010 Shell installed on our production box, too many client issues are unreproducible in our test environment, and without it we are stuck guessing what is wrong. With it, we can pull in few pages of production source code and break point the process to find out directly. It shaves hours to days off bug fix times.

Comment: I will have to double check on Time Zone Redirection, with this being a leased server from a professional farm this is a real possibility, i will research how to determine this, and check.

Comment: As for confusion of remote desktop, this would be hard, i run a 3240x1920 local desktop across three monitors in portrait mode, my RDP window takes up less than 1/4 of this real estate in the upper right hand corner of my desktop, plus if you look closely in my most recent screen scrape, you will notice the edge of the RDP window along the bottom and right side of the image, those borders could be present if that were the local task bar.

Comment: I think i already covered the remote debug scenario, as we are not remote debugging, i RDP to our production data server, open VS Shell on the remote desktop, open a specific CS file or two, and either set a break point or Catch all exceptions on thrown, and attach to the application pool process. I think that completely eliminates any concerns for execution space considerations.

Comment: Hey Mike - perhaps this might be better diagnosed interactively.  Would you like some assistance? You can reach me on Skype under the skype name "mattj1856".